# Toshiba laptop won't boot with third-party laptop battery?

Tags: battery, toshiba-laptop

I recently purchased a new third-party battery for my Toshiba M700 tablet/laptop. The battery fits fine and the tablet detects and charges it, but when I try to boot up all I get is the Toshiba logo then a flashing cursor in the top-left.  I can get to the BIOS, but no further.

If I put the old battery back in, everything boots up fine.

Has anyone else seen this problem?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely the battery you purchased is either defective or is not really "compatible" with your model of tablet.  This is not an uncommon problem with third party batteries.  I would recommend verifying first, that the battery is indeed compatible with your exact model of tablet.  If it is, then I would recommend you return it and exchange it for another one.

Laptop batteries are not strictly batteries.  They also contain some electronics.  Dell is especially notorious for their laptops not recognizing non-Dell batteries and it often requires bios updates to fix.  You might check with Toshiba to see if there is a bios update to fix issues with recognizing batteries.

Comment: Thanks BBlake. After your comment, I updated my bios from v1.40 to v1.80 - no difference.  The vendor confirmed that the battery model is supposed to be compatible with my current battery and will send out a replacement free of charge.  I'll post back here if that solves the problem.

Thanks again!

Comment: Received the new battery.  This doesn't work either.  I will be asking for a refund and purchasing a genuine Toshiba one.

Comment: @FuzzyPurpleMonkey - Good to hear you solved your problem! You should add those comments as an answer, Whilst BBlake's answers the general case, it would be helpful to document your specific case as well :). (Comments don't have history/backups, and could be lost forever if removed)

Answer (score 1):

I found out from a local battery supplier that Toshiba batteries are essentially region-locked.

I bought the laptop from America, which means that it only works with American-coded batteries (even though almost all online battery resellers don't tell you this).

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  It is very useful information.  BTW, I suspect the third party battery resellers probably don't know this.